# google cloud compute usage export to a storage not working

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

I've enabled usage export setting for my google cloud compute engine platform and set a bucket for destination storage.

It has been almost 27 hours but the report it not there in the bucket.

I've read this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/usage-export) and followed exact same steps.

I've checked the status with gcloud using following code

```
gcloud compute project-info describe
```

It shows correct bucket name in usageExportLocation.

Does the storage class of bucket matters? I've coldline storage class bucket.

Answer (score 0):

It has started working.

If you have requested the usage export report during 1st day of the month, It will start exporting usage of 2nd day at 3rd day. So you will not start getting report of the same exact day from another day, you will have to wait one more day.

But of course the report for requested day will be inside the total usage report of current month as they will provide following two formats.

- Daily Report
- Current Month Report

Answer (score 0):

As stated(below) in the help center article about '[Setting up usage export](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/usage-export#setting_up_usage_export)';

> " When you first enable the usage export feature, the first report will
>   be sent the following day, detailing the previous day's usage.
>   Afterwards, you will receive reports in 24 hour intervals."

This is an expected behavior, when you **first** enable **the usage export feature**.